# physics contact errors since iOS8 - object collisions when objects are not close together

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, collision, game-physics, skphysicsbody

My game was working fine in iOS7, since iOS 8, I am having contact occur with physics bodies that are not even close to each other. I verified this by enabling 'showphysics' - also the error always seems to be with a newly created object which is offscreen..

Has anyone seen this, and know any way of fixing this issue?

If you can see in this screenshot, there are birds and butterflies flying around.. a collision has just occured with the ball and an object which is offscreen!, and the NSLog is showing the two objects, and their X positions.. they aren't even close.. one clue, the second body is always newly created, and offscreen to the right ( > screen.x, but never < 0 ).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: you should also log the node's y pos and their frames, and convert the x/y coordinates to scene coordinates - if they have different parents they might still overlap depending on parent position

Comment: Thanks LC2D... All objects are children of the Mainscene..  When any object is onscreen, the collisions are working fine. This "ghost" collision is also always happening when the offscreen object is off to the right (> 320x ) and never when the object created offscreen is to the left ( < 0x).. and the ball also acts as if it hit something. 

Also don't forget if I run in iOS 7.1 the issue isn't there..

Comment: Ok I did solve this issue.. the problem was when using negative (-1) xScale on objects to flip the texture horizontally... this messed up the physics body.  the solution was simply to re-initialize the physics body, AFTER setting the negative xScale..

object.physicsBody = object.physicsBody;